# Array as 'key' in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, loop, meta-query

The first query is working fine individually. Vouchers have a day, a start time and an end time. I'm grabbing the current time (e.g 11:10) and trying to show posts where the `$time_now` comes BETWEEN the `start_time` and `end_time`. Are you not able to pass an array into the `key`?

```
$today = date('l');
$time_now = date('H:i');

    $args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'voucher' ),
        'meta_query'             => array(
            array(
                'key'       => '_voucher_days_available',
                'value'     => $today,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                'type'      => 'CHAR',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => array('_voucher_start_time','_voucher_end_time'),
                'value' => $time_now,
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
        ),
    );
```

Comment: What kind of value does _voucher_start_time hold? is it numeric, timestamp, or something else?

Comment: @AhmedMahdi It's saved simply as a string "14:00" using https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#text_time

Comment: So just to recap $time_now is somethin like 16:00 start time is 14:00 and end time is saved as 18:00 for example. Is that correct please?

Comment: @AhmedMahdi Correct. I'm looking to get all vouchers inside that time frame.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestion by @AhmedMahdi to solve your problem, here's the narrower answer to your question: Nope, `key` cannot be an array. As you can see in the [specs of WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) `key` must be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the following `$args`

```
$today = date('l');
$time_now = date('H:i');

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'voucher' ),
    'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => '_voucher_days_available',
                'value'     => $today,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                'type'      => 'CHAR',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => '_voucher_start_time',
                'value'     => $time_now,
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'type'      => 'date'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => '_voucher_end_time',
                'value'     => $time_now,
                'compare'   => '<=',
                'type'      => 'date'
            ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is still returning 0 results despite the criteria being met in the database.

Comment: Ah, I know. Both 'compare' should be '>='

Comment: Actually no, that's still not done the trick.

Comment: What this query do is ensure that time now is between (ranges) of voucher start time and voucher end time, please ensure that the data is set / received as a date.